# Resolution in FOL? Renaming and substituting variables?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I would just like to know if this is the correct way to do resolution in FOL.

Original Clauses:

1. ¬p(x,y) ∨ p(y,x)
2. ¬p(x,y) ∨ ¬p(y,z) ∨ p(x,z)
3. p(x,f(x))
4. ¬p(x,x)

Renaming variables:

1. [x/x1], [y/y1]
2. [x/x2], [y/y2]
3. [x/x3],
4. [x/x4]

Renamed clauses:

1. ¬p(x1,y1) ∨ p(y1,x1)
2. ¬p(x2,y2) ∨ ¬p(y2,z) ∨ p(x2,z)
3. p(x3,f(x3))
4. ¬p(x4,x4)

New/resolvent clauses:

5. Substitutions: Clause1 - [y1/f(x1)], Clause 3 - [ x3/ x1].

   Resolvent Clause from clause1 & clause 3: p(f(x1), x1)
6. Substitutions: Clause2 - [y2/f(x1)], [z /x1], Clause 3 - [ x3/ x1].

   Resolvent Clause from clause2 & clause 5: ¬p(x2,f(x1) ∨ ¬p(x2,x1)
7. Substitutions: Clause6 - [ x2/ x4],[ x1/ x4].

   Resolvent Clause from clause4 & clause 6: ¬p(x4,f(x4))
8. Substitutions: Clause7 - [ x4/ x3]

   Resolvent Clause from clause3 & clause 7:[]

So, I would like to know if my approach is correct? Also, I will like to know when I could not make a substitution? Are these the only kind of substitutions I can't make, [x/x] and [x/f(x)]?

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! Good job!  And you're right, as long as we don't substitute a variable for a complex term involving function symbols, we're good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

Maybe try with a "smart" approach, prior to any renaming:

- subst $x \to z$ in 1) and 2) to get:

5) $¬p(x,y) ∨ p(x,x)$

- resolve with 4) to get:

6) $¬p(x,y)$.

Now we have :

3) $p(x,f(x))$

6) $¬p(x,y)$.

Now we can unify with subst: $f(x) \to y$.

---

Also with your initial renaming, I'll try with:

- subst $x_4 \to z$ and $x_4 \to x_2$ in 2) to get:

2') $¬p(x_4,y_2) ∨ ¬p(y_2,x_4) ∨ p(x_4,x_4)$

and resolve with 4) to get:

5) $¬p(x_4,y_2) ∨ ¬p(y_2,x_4)$.

Then subst $x_4 \to x_1$ and $y_2 \to y_1$ in 1) to get:

1') $¬p(x_4,y_2) ∨ p(y_2,x_4)$

and resolve with 5) to get:

6) $¬p(x_4,y_2)$.

Now we have:

3) $p(x_3,f(x_3))$

6) $¬p(x_4,y_2)$

and we can define the final subst to resolve them.

Comment: Oh, that seems much easier than renaming. Is there any specific case in which you have to rename? My professor told me if your clauses have the same variables you should always rename them. Is that a must or is it just make it less confusing?